# Cannot navigate to CodeIgniter site

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I have a Ubuntu server with 2 websites on it. I can navigate to one, but not to the other. Here are the details:

Each website has a user with the same name as the group and as the subfolder. Sites are hosted under
`/home/site1/public_html` and 
`/home/site2/public_html`

Now in my case site1 is called from a subdomain, but it works just fine, so if I navigate to `site1.mydomain.com` it opens up the CodeIgniter page and I can navigate with no issues (I have .htaccess here to get rid of index.php in the url).

However when I try to navigate to `www.site2.com` which points to `/home/site2/public_html` it gives me a 404 error. So to troubleshoot, I added a `/home/site2/public_html/index.html` simple file and I can see that if I navigate to `www.site2.com`, however I can't see it if I navigate to `www.site2.com/index.html`. Also, in my case, I have a subfolder  (with same name as the site = "site2") where CodeIgniter code/folder structure is and I just can't get tot that index.php from code igniter at all (path to it is `/home/site2/public_html/site2/index.php`). I tried to navigate as `www.site2.com/site2/index.php` or `www.site2.com/index.php` with or without htaccess file but with no help. I tried to remove the `.htaccess` in this site, I tried to create a `test.html` in `/home/site2/public_html/site2` but I can't navigate to it, I get 404 if I do `www.site2.com/site2/test.html`

in terms of user access I used `$ chmod -R 755 /home/site2`

Is it an access right that I am missing? Or a conflict with the other .htaccess from the other virtual folder? No clue... and I am just running out of ideas

V Host Settings

```
ServerName site1.mydomain.com
ServerAlias site1.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "/home/site1/public_html"
<Directory "/home/site1/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and for the one I've trouble with

```
ServerName www.site2.com
ServerAlias www.site2.com
DocumentRoot "/home/site2/public_html"
<Directory "/home/site2/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

NOTE : I just made a subdomain site2.mydomain.com (domain registered with FatCow) and that seems to be working, it does not work only when I call it with www.site2.com (register under GoDaddy - which gives a GoDaddy "Destination unknown" page which I assumed it is a 404 error and always asks me to Accept cookies ... and I am on a diet :P )

Thanks anyone in advance!

Comment: you should post your vhost settings ...

Comment: vhost settings are in (see last part in the question)

Comment: See this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/337874/change-apache-document-root-folder-to-secondary-hard-drive) maybe you need to modify your root folder in linux

Comment: If you look in V Host settings you can see that I have a DocumentRoot there, I've also tried to add the additional clauses in the conf file - options additional params as per your link, still no luck.

What I don't get is why it works just fine with subdomain but now with domain... 
I also called GoDaddy and they say all traffic is directed permanently to my server, there shouldn't be any GoDaddy page, yet it is a GoDaddy page I'm seeing.

Comment: then it looks like a dns problem .... (ping www.site2.com and ping www.site1.com) do they ping the same IP address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh darn thing, you were right @sintakonte, one site was pointing somewhere else. Go daddy had a A record with old IP address, I added another A record and asked them to park the original (as I had no rights to do so from their website). And problem got resolved. Thank you!